# How to create circular polygon in openlayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, circle

So i would really like to modify this example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/tissot.html?q=circle

Problem is that when I try to apply it to my map it doesn't work, probably because I use OSM style which is not spherical:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
    new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    })
  ],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([2.1833, 41.3833], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

And for the question: how to create circular polygon?
As I can see, there are two choices:

1. Somehow convert geom.Circle in geom.Polygon, which I can't do, based on my noob level
2. Create my own function to do that, something like openlayers 2:

   OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon = function(origin, radius, sides, rotation) {
       var angle = Math.PI * ((1/sides) - (1/2));
       if(rotation) {
           angle += (rotation / 180) * Math.PI;
       }
       var rotatedAngle, x, y;
       var points = [];
       for(var i=0; i

Has anyone got to the same point in their GIS master life? Which one is better? or is there a hidden path, that only Wise and Strong ones can see? Help me please!

Answer (score 15):

As others have correctly pointed out, the GeoJSON and WKT formats do not support circular geometries in any way.  Circles are not in the KML specification either. This makes it a pain when trying to write out a map frame to KML, GeoJSON or WKT.

OpenLayers v3 does have a way to approximate a circle with a polygon, but it isn't pretty as it involves converting to great circle distance.  See the API reference for the `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` method here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Polygon.html#circular

An example of the `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` method is shown below, but can also be seen in this [OpenLayers tissot indicatrix example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/tissot.html).

```js
 var lowpoly = ol.geom.Polygon.circular(
  /* WGS84 Sphere */
  new ol.Sphere(6378137),
  circle.getCenter(),
  circle.getRadius(),
  /* Number of verticies */
  12);
```

Alternatively, you can use `fromCircle` which, at the time of this post, is experimental.

```js
var lowpoly = ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle(
  circle,
  /* Number of verticies (optional) */
  12,
  /* Start angle (optional) */
  90
);
```

For something that you can play with, see my jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a1syw4od/9/

Comment: I could propose an edit, but maybe it's easier if you fix it: the last example should use `ol.geom.Polygon.fromCircle ` rather than `ol.geom.Polygon.circular`. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in creating a simple circular polygon then use:

```
new ol.geom.Circle(
            ol.proj.transform([longitude, latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            radius_meters),
            'XY'
        )
```

Source: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html
(remove the stable tick at the top of the page)

Comment: This is valid, but currently has problems if you intend to try and convert the feature into GeoJSON. See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3237#issuecomment-78475413

Comment: also when you try to extract geometry in wkt using writeWKT.

Comment: `ol.geom.Circle` is not a polygon, it is a simple geometry represented by a radius and center.  (see the base class of `ol.geom.Circle` is `ol.geom.SimpleGeometry` not `ol.geom.Polygon`)  GeoJSON, WKT, and KML do not have circular geometries in their specification and require conversion before formatting.  Please see my answer for a way to approximate an `ol.geom.Circle` by a true polygon.