# Using WKT.writeGeometry for 'Circle' Geometry in OpenLayers?

Tags: geometry, openlayers, well-known-text, circle

In my application which I'm building using OpenLayers3, I'm trying to extract the geometry of a feature to WKT using 
`var format = new ol.format.WKT();
console.log(format.writeGeometry(geometry));` by following [this](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html#writeGeometry) docs.

 It works great for Polygon as I have tested, i.e. returning the Geometry String (WKT) but it fails when I try to apply it to `Circle` Geometry. In particular the log is printed as
  `Assertion failed: geometryEncoder should be defined`

So, is there any solution to this as why this is particularly happening with `Circle` geometries. And how to resolve it, i.e. where to define this `geometryEncoder` as suggested in log?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122381/how-to-create-circular-polygon-in-openlayers-3/148219

Answer (score 6):

The circle geometry (a center with a radius) is not a supported by the WKT format.

Your best chance is to transofrm your Circle geometry in an approximate Polygon with the [circular function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html#.circular)

Comment: link no longer works.  I ended up using the solution i found here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122381/how-to-create-circular-polygon-in-openlayers-3

Comment: link fixed, thx