# Converting feature from draw interaction to WKT string

Tags: openlayers, well-known-text, draw-interaction

I've problems with converting the feature which I'm getting in draw interaction into the WKT string. I saw multiple examples which looks like it should be simple but I'm always getting the following exception while calling `format.writeGeometry()` function:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function getDrawInteraction() {
    return new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: this.source, //it is ol.source.Vector() for my layer
        stopClick: true,
        type: "Circle"
    });
}

function draw() {              
    var drawInteraction = getDrawInteraction(),
        format = new ol.format.WKT();

    drawInteraction.on("drawend", function (event) {
        var feature = event.feature,
            wkt;

        wkt = format.writeGeometry(feature.getGeometry());

    });
    map.addInteraction(drawInteraction);        
}
```

I'm able to draw a circle on the map but what I am doing wrong WKT string?

Comment: WKT (and GeoJSON) doesn't support Circle (it's not a standard geometry type outside of OpenLayers).  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144617/using-wkt-writegeometry-for-circle-geometry-in-openlayers/145073

Comment: I'm new to OpenLayers and I didn't know that! It might help me a lot, thanks!